# How define a function in PYTHON with differente parameters from a series expansion

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am trying to define a new function starting from a series expansion calculated in another function. I'm going to write down part of the code.

In my code a have,

```
def secondtype_CB(theta,channel,u): 
    return series(limit_ConfB(theta,channel,u),lamb,oo,1).removeO()

Jhat = secondtype_CB(theta,channel,u)
```

where the first function returns a series expansion which depends on many parameters for example `th0`, `tht`, `nu`, and `t`. I want to use this return series to define a new function `Jhat` as `Jhat(tht,th0, nu,t)`. It seems to be easy, perhaps it is because I'm studying Python in the slow mode.

Edited:

Let me explain better, in my code, I obtain from secondtype_CB(theta, channel,u) the following series

> 1 + ((th0^2 - tht^2)ths-2(th0^2 + tht^2 + 2ths^2)nu + 16nu^3)/(4t)

Here, I'm only showing the first two terms of the series. Now, the idea is to define the function Jhat which depends on the parameters in the series.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this?

```
def secondtype_CB(theta,channel,u): 
    
    def Jhat(lamb, oo):
        return series(limit_ConfB(theta,channel,u),lamb,oo,1).removeO()

    return Jhat
```